# Influxdb python 5.3.1 write_points not allowing multiple rows to be written

Tags: python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am new to using influxdb (v1.7.4), and I am using its python module ([influxdb-python](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python)).
I want to write data in bulk into influxdb.
But unable to get the correct output when using the `write_points` method.

```
point = [
        {
            "fields": {
                "PATH": "/",
                "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "10"
            },
            "measurement": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "PATH": "/xxxxxxxxx",
                "DISK_USED_PERCENT": "0"
            },
            "measurement": "xxxxxxx"
        }
        ]

client.write_points(point)
```

I want to add multiple points in a go. As per the documentation, it can be done by providing a list of dictionaries.
But the result I'm seeing is only taking the last item from the list and creating a ResultSet with it.

```
ResultSet({'('xxxxxxx', None)': [{'time': '2021-05-10T09:38:20.818555Z', 'DISK_USED_PERCENT': '0', 'PATH': '/xxxxxxxxx'}]})
```

Any leads would be appreciated.